# How do I use the parameter of a function within a smaller, nested function in Node.js/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I am trying to write a validator function for my POST request bodies. Since the validation process repeats multiple times throughout my project, I wrote a function in `validate.js` for that purpose so that I could use it repeatedly elsewhere.

Here is my code for the function in `validate.js`, which takes in the function validator as a parameter so it could be applied to `req.body` on line 3:

```
module.exports = function (validator) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        const { error } = validator(req.body); 
        if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
        next();
    }
}
```

I then proceed to use this function as the middleware in POST methods, for example:

```
router.post('/', validate(validateUser), async (req, res) => {
    ...
});
```

with the `validateUser` function looking as follows:

```
function validateUser(user) {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
        email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
        password: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required(),
        class: Joi.number().min(1900).max(maxYear).required(),
        major: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required(),
    };

    return Joi.validate(user, schema);
}
```

This, however, gives me a "not an error" function that I can't seem to fix. I suspect that it has something to do with the fact that `validator` lies beyond scope of the return function, so the `validator` inside is basically an undeclared variable. How should I fix this? Thank you!

Here is the error:

```
{"level":"error","message":"validator is not a function validator is not a function", "stack":"TypeError: validator is not a function
at D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\middleware\\validate.js:3:21
at newFn (D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express-async-errors\\index.js:16:20)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:112:3)
at newFn (D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express-async-errors\\index.js:16:20)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)
at D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:174:3)
at router (D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:47:12) 
at newFn (D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express-async-errors\\index.js:16:20)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:317:13)
at D:\\projects\\vikingreviews\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:284:7"}
```

Comment: `var middleWare =  validate(validateUser);
router.post('/', middleWare, async (req, res) => {
    ...
});`

Comment: can you also show how are you doing a `require` on the `validate` function and also what is `typeof validateUser`

Comment: const validate = require('../middleware/validate'); And validateUser is a function.

Comment: Wat are you getting for `var middleWare =  validate(validateUser); typeof  middleWare`

Comment: I would also put console.log or debugger in the middleware function and see what is the value in `validator ` argument

Comment: @lshank It still displays the same error. `typeof(middleware)` returns `function`.

Comment: The error says that `validator ` is not a function, can you check what is its value? maybe put a debugger inside the validate.js - middleware function - `console.log(validator);`?

Comment: `validator ` is not an undeclared variable else the error message would have been different, it's not a function is what the error message says, it doesn't say that its undefined or something like that so try `console.log(validator)` and see what's the value in line 3 in validate.js.

Comment: Possibly something is not right in the way you might have required `validateUser ` function, post the code that shows how you are requiring the `validateUser `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this -

```
router.post('/', validate((user) => {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
        email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
        password: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required(),
        class: Joi.number().min(1900).max(maxYear).required(),
        major: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required(),
    };

    return Joi.validate(user, schema);
}), async (req, res) => {
    res.send('OK');
});
```

this because I doubt seeing the error message that you are not passing the `validateUser` method correctly. This way we are directly passing the function and confirm if the error is because you are passing the validator function in maybe a wrong way

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out and indeed wasn't passing the method correctly. My export was `module.exports.validate = ...` but my require statement was `const validateUser = require(...)`. Once I changed the former to `module.exports.validateUser` it worked.

Comment: that's good, any possibility to upvote or accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express(),
Joi = require('joi');
maxYear = 3000;

const test = () => {
 return (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers['content-type'] !== 'application/json') {
    res.status(400).send('Server requires application/json')
   } else {
      next()
   }
  }
 }

function validateUser(user) {

const Schema = Joi.object({
name: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
password: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required(),
class: Joi.number().min(1900).max(maxYear).required(),
major: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required(),
});
 console.log("Error", Schema.validate(Schema, user).error)
 return Schema.validate(user);
}

module.exports = validate = function (validator) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
  const { error } = validator(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
     next();
  }
 }

 app.post('/test', validate(validateUser), async (req, res) => {
   console.log("Testing")
  });


 app.post('/', test(), (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('You sent JSON in the request');
  })

  app.listen(3000);
```

You need to define the validate function as I did to one of your function.